# String Doubly Linked List of 4 characters each node

Tags: c++, string, doubly-linked-list

I want to accept a long string of numbers and insert in to a doubly linked list , with each node having 4 characters(numbers).
Below is my code. It takes the input as number, but says "Program finished with exist code 0"
Please help what did I am miss here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
struct Node {
  string data;
  struct Node* prev;
  struct Node* next;
};
struct Node* head = NULL;
void insert(string newdata) {
  struct Node* newnode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  newnode->data = newdata;
  newnode->prev = NULL;
  newnode->next = head;
  if (head != NULL)
    head->prev = newnode;
  head = newnode;
  cout << "\nNode inserted";
}

void display() {
  struct Node* ptr;
  ptr = head;
  while (ptr != NULL) {
    cout << ptr->data << " ";
    ptr = ptr->next;
  }
}
int main() {
  string n1, temp;
  cout << "Enter the number\n";
  cin >> n1;
  int len, i;
  len = n1.size();
  cout << "\n Length is " << len;
  getch();
  // temp= n1;

  // cout<<"\n line is "<<temp.substr(len);

  for (i = 0; i < len; i = i + 4) {
    //     temp = n1.substr(i,4);
    insert(n1.substr(i, 4));
  }

  cout << "\nThe doubly linked list is: ";
  display();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `malloc` with `Node`, because Node's constructor won't run and you'll access an uninitialized string object. Use `newnode = new Node;` (and give Node a proper constructor so you won't have to assign to every field).

Comment: An alternative would be to explicitly construct the `string` object in-place, using [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new). However, that is not good C++ programming style. But it would be more in line with OP's C-style solution.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in the comments section, the problem is that the constructor of the `std::string` object is not getting called, so that this object is not initialized properly.

The most straightforward fix to this would be to use [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), which effectively does nothing else than to call the constructor. In order to do this, you can change the line

```
newnode->data = newdata;
```

to

```
new (&newnode->data) string( newdata );
```

This will call the copy (or move) constructor on the `std::string` object.

However, a more C++ style solution to the problem would be not to use `malloc` at all, but to instead use `new`, and to write a proper constructor for `struct Node`, which invokes the copy or move constructor of the `string` object. In order to do this, you could define `struct Node` like this:

```
struct Node {

    //copy and move constructor
    Node( const string  &data, Node* prev = nullptr, Node* next = nullptr )
        : data(data), prev(prev), next(next) {}
    Node( const string &&data, Node* prev = nullptr, Node* next = nullptr )
        : data(data), prev(prev), next(next) {}

    string data;
    struct Node* prev;
    struct Node* next;
};
```

Now you can replace the lines

```
struct Node* newnode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
newnode->data = newdata;
newnode->prev = NULL;
newnode->next = head;
```

with this single line:

```
Node* newnode = new Node( newdata, nullptr, head );
```